# MongoDB Embedded Objects have no ID (null value)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I have a question regarding MongoDB with Spring Data. 
I have these domain classes:

```
@Document
public class Deal  {
    @Id
    private ObjectId _id;
    private Location location;
    private User user;
    private String description;
    private String title;
    private String price;
    private boolean approved;
    private Date expirationDate;
    private Date publishedDate;
}

@Document
public class Location {
    @Id
    private ObjectId _id;
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;
    private String country;
    private String street;
    private String zip;
}

@Document
public class User {
    @Id
    private ObjectId _id;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String profile_image_url;
    private Collection<Deal> deals = new ArrayList<Deal>();
}
```

With these domains I can successfully CRUD. There is only one problem. When saving a User with Deals, the deals and Location get _id set to null when saving them to MongoDB.
Why can´t MongoDB generate unique id´s for embedded objects?

The result after saving a User with one deal:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "4fed0591d17011868cf9c982" ),
  "_class" : "User",
  "email" : "milo@gmail.com",
  "password" : "mimi",
  "deals" : [ 
    { "_id" : null,
      "location" : { "_id" : null,
        "latitude" : 2.22,
        "longitude" : 3.23445,
        "country" : "Denmark",
        "street" : "Denmark road 77",
        "zip" : "2933" },
      "description" : "The new Nexus 7 Tablet. A 7 inch tablet from Google.",
      "title" : "Nexus 7",
      "price" : "1300",
      "approved" : false,
      "expirationDate" : Date( 1343512800000 ),
      "publishedDate" : Date( 1340933521374 ) } ] }
```

As you can see from the result, Deal and Location ID is set to NULL.

Comment: An ID identifies a root document, not sub-documents. There's no reason why you'd want to auto generate an id for a nested document as MongoDB can only retrieve top level documents anyway. What do you actually need the nested id for?

Comment: I need to search for only deals and not User. Now I have to search from User and then loop threw every deal in user programmatically.

Comment: The id has nothing to do with what you can search for. It's perfectly fine to search for `{ 'deals.price' : { $gt : 1000 }}`. Still, this query would return a `User` object you'd manually have to pull out the `Deal` from then. This is a MongoDB limitation, nothing implied by Spring Data.

Comment: You are correct. I have saved the user and deal separately, but email is shared with both of them. I can now get Deals alone without going threw users document and the same for users.

Answer (score 53):

MongoDB CRUD operations (`insert`, `update`, `find`, `remove`) all operate on top-level documents exclusively -- although of course you can filter by fields in embedded documents. Embedded documents are always returned within the parent document.

The `_id` field is a required field of the parent document, and is typically not necessary or present in embedded documents. If you require a unique identifier, you can certainly create them, and you may use the `_id` field to store them if that is convenient for your code or your mental model; more typically, they are named after what they represent (e.g. "username", "otherSystemKey", etc). Neither MongoDB itself, nor any of the drivers will automatically populate an `_id` field except on the top-level document.

Specifically in Java, if you wish to generate ObjectId values for the `_id` field in embedded documents, you can do so with:

```
someEmbeddedDoc._id = new ObjectId();
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up. So if I want to list only deals I have to separate or move the User document from the Deal document so that Deal is a separate document and User is a separated document and then query.

Comment: Either that or adjust your code to work with the existing data model. If you are frequently manipulating deals, or if deals are associated with more than one user, then normalizing the data model may make sense.

Answer (score 8):

In the context of a REST architecture it makes all the sense that nested docs have their own Ids.

1. Persistence implementation should be independent from resource representation. As an API consumer I don't care if you are using mongo or mysql. If you a nest docs without id in mongo try to imagine how to change the persistence layer to a relational data base. Now do the same exercise having thought beforehand with an implementation independent approach. Modeling nested docs in a relational db, root and nested docs will be different entities/tables each with their own ids. The root could have a one to many relationship with the nested doc.
2. I may need to access a nested doc directly instead of sequentially.I may not need absolute unique ids, like those issued by mongo, but I'll still need some local unique identifier. This is, unique within the root doc.

Having argued my point about the need of ids in nested docs @dcrosta has already given a correct answer on how to populate the _id field in mongo.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

An _id is not set on subdocuments by default only on root docuemnts.

You will need to define a _id for your subdocuments on insert and update.

Comment: Shouldn't he do that for me? how can I do that? Should I insert every document alone and them put them together? This is how I insert:       mongoOperation.insert(deal);

Comment: MongoDB won't do this for you but now that I take a second glance maybe your Driver should...are you using Morphia?

Comment: thanks for the replies. I'm using Spring Data and mongo-java-driver. When I search for deals I get a User object. I cannot search using Deals I have to go threw User and then query programmatically in User for deals.

Comment: I cannot query for only deals that have this latitude or this longitude. I have to query threw user which is the main document. Im confused.

Answer (score 7):

Mongo does not create or need `_id`s on embedded documents. You can add an `_id` field if you want - I have done it.

```
@Document
public class Location {
    @Id
    private ObjectId _id;

    public Location() {
        this._id = ObjectId.get();
    }
}

@Document
public class User {
    @Id
    private ObjectId _id;

    public User() {
        this._id = ObjectId.get();
    }
}
```

This works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers no longer apply now. Every sub documents gets an `_id` automatically.
In fact, to avoid applying an `_id` to a subdocument, you have to explicitly pass the option

```
{ _id: false }
```

in the subdocument schema.