# Spring-data-mongo unable to instantiate java.util.List using Constructor

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Using `spring-data-mongodb-1.5.4`  and `mongodb-driver-3.4.2`

I've a class `Hotel`

```
    public class Hotel {

        private String name;
        private int pricePerNight;
        private Address address;
        private List<Review> reviews;
//getter, setter, default constructor, parameterized constructor
```

`Review` class :

```
public class Review {

    private int rating;
    private String description;
    private User user;
    private boolean isApproved;
 //getter, setter, default constructor, parameterized constructor
```

When I am calling `Aggregation.unwind("reviews");` it throws

> org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException:
>   Failed to instantiate java.util.List using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR
>   with arguments

```
UnwindOperation unwindOperation = Aggregation.unwind("reviews");
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(unwindOperation);
AggregationResults<Hotel> results=mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation,"hotel", Hotel.class);
```

I see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361297/why-is-spring-data-mongodb-unable-to-instantiate-this-nested-type-structure) but does't help me.

How to resolve this?

Comment: 9/10 times you really just want a plain BSON object like `Document.class` or `DBObject.class`  for the aggregation output. Aggregations change the output shape by definition of what they are meant to do. Typically you just don't need a strict type for output, unless you really **need** some custom serialization. For everything else, just use the generics. That's what they are there for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you `$unwind` `reviews` field, query's return json structure does not match with your `Hotel`class anymore. Because `$unwind`operation makes `reviews` a sub object instead of a list. If you try your query in robomongo or some other tools, you can see your return object is like that

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("59b519d72f9e340bcc830cb3"),
  "id" : "59b23c39c70ff63135f76b14",
  "name" : "Signature",
  "reviews" : {
    "id" : 1,
    "userName" : "Salman",
    "rating" : 8,
    "approved" : true
  }
}
```

So you should use another class instead of `Hotel`like `UnwindedHotel`

```
public class UnwindedHotel {

    private String name;
    private int pricePerNight;
    private Address address;
    private Review reviews;
}

UnwindOperation unwindOperation = Aggregation.unwind("reviews");
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(unwindOperation);
AggregationResults<UnwindedHotel> results=mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation,"hotel", UnwindedHotel.class);
```

Comment: You saved me again :)

Comment: @MehrajMalik  Happy to help. And a general suggestion which I do for my queries. First build them as native mongodb query and try it directly via robomongo etc. Then code it into spring-data. So you can be sure your query works and return values as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the golden tip.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs to me a very different problem making me crazy for long time a day ago and I think it could be very useful to share here even if it is not about unwind:

- at the beginning I design a model with java + mongoDB in which I put some fields in a key inside a document and made several tests, for example `{"header":{"key":"first", "value": 4}}`
- then I changed my mind and think not to have simple nested objects but a list of them to be more general such as `{"header":[{"key":"first", "value": 4}] }`

When I was working only with new documents all was running fine, but then making more general tests I continuously had crashes with this mongodb error about List because in my DB I had old documents without list but with simple objects I forgot to remove and which were in conflict with the new model wanting a list.

Simple had I to clean DB and starting tests from scratch.