# Aggregation using lookup, unwind and project getting "Failed to instantiate java.util.List using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments" while

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, aggregation-framework

spring-data-mongodb-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar and mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar

I have below classes

```
@Document(collection = "customers")
data class Customer (
    @Id var _id: ObjectId? = null,
    var custId: String? = null,
    var custName: String? = null,
    var accounts: List<Account>? = null
) : Serializable
```

Account class :

```
@Document(collection = "accounts")
    data class Account (
        @Id var _id: ObjectId? = null,
        var custId: String? = null,
        var accountId: String? = null,
        var accountType: String? = null
        
) : Serializable
```

I am looking at below output

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d092132237909001a398cc5"), "custId" : {"123"}, { "custName"  : { "Test"}  }, "accounts" : { "accountId" : {"000079537"} : { "accountType" : "Savings" } } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d092132237909001a398cc5"), "custId" : { "123" },  { "custName" : "Test"  }, "accounts" : { "accountId" : {"000079538"},  {"accountType" : "Current" } } }
```

In mongo shell below script is giving the above output. But when we turn to java with below code we are seeing "Failed to instantiate java.util.List using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments" I followed [Spring-data-mongo unable to instantiate java.util.List using Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46139856/spring-data-mongo-unable-to-instantiate-java-util-list-using-constructor) but still we are seeing the same issue.

```
db.getCollection("customers").aggregate([{ "$match" : { "$and" : [{ "custId" : "123"}, ]}},
            { "$lookup" : { "from" : "accounts", "localField" : "custId", "foreignField" : "accounts.custId", "as" : "accounts"}}
           , { "$unwind" : "$accounts"}, { "$project" : {  "custId" : 1, "accounts.accountType" : "$accounts.accountType"}} 

        ]
        )
```

Aggregate code

```
val unwindOperation = Aggregation.unwind("accounts") 
val lookUp = Aggregation.lookup( lookUpCollectionDetails!!.collection, lookUpCollectionDetails.localField, lookUpCollectionDetails.foreignField, lookUpCollectionDetails.attribute ) 
val limit = Aggregation.limit(mongoResultLimit.toLong()) 
val aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation( Customer::class.java, match, lookUp, unwindOperation, projectionOperation, limit )
```

Comment: please share the aggregation query code. Is it java or kotlin? Also share the complete error

Comment: I think the error is telling that you need a constructor with properties and include particuler property. And, the code `{ "$match" : { "$and" : [{ "custId" : "123"}, ]}` can be simply: ``{ "$match" : { "custId" : "123"} }`.

Comment: val unwindOperation = Aggregation.unwind("accounts")
  val lookUp = Aggregation.lookup(
    lookUpCollectionDetails!!.collection,
    lookUpCollectionDetails.localField,
    lookUpCollectionDetails.foreignField,
    lookUpCollectionDetails.attribute
   )

  val limit = Aggregation.limit(mongoResultLimit.toLong())
  val aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
   Customer::class.java, match, lookUp, unwindOperation,
   projectionOperation, limit
  )

Comment: @sidgate - When I remove the unwindOperation, I see below error

LinkedList cannot be mapped to String

Comment: You didn't share the `projectionOperation`

Comment: @sidgate val projectionOperation = ProjectionOperation(Fields.fields("custName", "accounts.accountType", "accounts.accountId"))