# Best Way to Create MongoDB Projections with Nested Objects in Spring Boot Data

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

I'm in the process of taking an existing MongoDB collection and wrapping it in a Repository in a Spring Boot application. Documents can be very large, so in many cases we only want to pull back a subset of the fields contained in it. When I try to do a projection that involves nested objects, I get a `MappingInstantiationException`.

I have an object structure like this:

```
@Document
data class OuterDocument(
    @Id
    val id: String,
    val bar: String,
    val nested: NestedDocument
)

data class NestedDocument(
    val nestedFoo: String
)

// This is the class I want to project into
data class OuterDto(
    val id: String,
    val nested: NestedDocument
)
```

My repository looks like this:

```
interface OuterRepository: MongoRepository<OuterDocument, String> {
    @Query("{id:  ?0}")
    fun getDto(id: String): OuterDto?
}
```

When calling this, I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate OuterDto using constructor fun <init>(kotlin.String, NestedDocument): OuterDto with arguments null,null
    at app//org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:290)
    at app//org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:102)
    at app//org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.doReadProjection(MappingMongoConverter.java:374)
...
```

I am unsure if this approach is *supposed* to work, but tracing through the code, it seems to be trying really hard to do it, and it *does* work when there are no nested objects (so, eg. if I replaced `nested` with `bar` in my DTO, it would be fine).

This seems similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361297/why-is-spring-data-mongodb-unable-to-instantiate-this-nested-type-structure), but I'm not nesting my type declarations, which seemed to be the root issue there.

Is the form shown by `getDto` supposed to work? Is there some modification I need to make to my classes or function?

Answer (score 0):

Doing an explicit pipeline with a projection seems to work in all scenarios (nested objects or not):

```
@Aggregation(pipeline = [
    "{ \$match: { id: ?0 } }",
    "{ \$project: { id: 1, nested: 1 } }",
])
fun getDto(id: String): OuterDto?
```

This is a reasonable fallback. The only downside is that in practice the projection requires a lot more fields and those need to be kept in sync with the DTO; it would be great if the framework could just infer which fields to project (as it seems to when no nested objects are present).