# MongoDB don't save null values for _id fields of nested documents

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I use mongoDB + spring-data to save my POJO instance in Java.
The example is nicely described in the question
[MongoDB Embedded Objects have no ID (null value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255100/mongodb-embedded-objects-have-no-id-null-value)

But I have a bit another question to the situation.
Can I avoid writing null values for _id of nested documents?

I checked documentation and didn't found any info on generating null values of nested docs
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.10.10.RELEASE/reference/html/#mapping.conventions.id-field

From Docs:
*If a field named id is declared as a String or BigInteger in the Java class it will be converted to and stored as an ObjectId if possible. ObjectId as a field type is also valid. If you specify a value for id in your application, the conversion to an ObjectId is detected to the MongoDBdriver. If the specified id value cannot be converted to an ObjectId, then the value will be stored as is in the document’s _id field.*

And also, for nested objects it is stored as single String, and isn't converted to ObjectId()

Comment: Are  you trying to store a real Id for the nested objects, or are you wanting nothing at all to be written out?

Comment: In nested objects there are some fields, that has naming 'id' and by design they can be null, so on null values I don't want they will be reflected in MongoDB as _id = null