# Difference: Mongoose populate and Embedded document

Tags: mongoose

What would be an ideal situation to use Mongoose populate and Embedded document, why would i choose one over other? Advantages and disadvantages. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is it depends! It depends on the Use Case and the way your system is. There are couple of good resources to give you insight on that.

Here is one Stackoverflow answer: 
[MongoDB relationships: embed or reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373198/a-simple-mongodb-question-embed-or-reference/5373969#5373969)

There is a complete book, containing several use cases and discussing on the same topic. You may find it a good read:

[http://www.amazon.com/MongoDB-Applied-Design-Patterns-Copeland/dp/1449340040/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449340040)

It contains several use cases of a Social Networking site, CMS, Ecommerce, Online Gaming etc.