# Design mongodb schema use embed or reference?

Tags: mongodb, reference

I want to design a user structure with some messages, but I don't know which relationship to use for messages: embed or reference?

have a structure like this:

**use embed:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5285a6449df8156c1b000fa3")
    "name" : "Lee NC",
    "message" : [{
            "_id" : ObjectId("5285a6449df8156c1b0002ed"),
            "message" : "message 1",
            "date" : ISODate("2013-11-15T04:42:43.0Z"),
        }, {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5285a6669df8156012000be0"),
            "message" : "message 2",
            "date" : ISODate("2013-11-15T04:43:17.0Z"),

        },
        ..........................................
        ..........................................
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5285a6669df8156012000be2"),
            "message" : "message N",
            "date" : ISODate("2013-11-15T04:43:17.0Z"),

        },
    ]
}
```

**or use "reference"**

```
user= {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5285a6449df8156c1b000fa3")
        "name" : "Lee NC",
        "message" : [{
                "message_id" : ObjectId("5285a6449df8156c1b0002ed")
            }, {
                "message_id" : ObjectId("5285a6669df8156012000be0")

            },
            ..........................................
            ..........................................
            {
                "message_id" : ObjectId("5285a6669df8156012000be2")

            },
        ]
    }
```

and

```
  message={
                "_id" : ObjectId("5285a6449df8156c1b0002ed"),
                "message" : "message 1",
                "date" : ISODate("2013-11-15T04:42:43.0Z"),
            },
```

Comment: What's your programming question? You didn't add any detail about how the documents are used, queries, performance, etc. Start here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models/

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB relationships: embed or reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373198/mongodb-relationships-embed-or-reference)

Comment: System sends automatic text message to user and message is read only.
One user will be million messages

Comment: @SangNguyen When a user has millions of messages, you need to place them in individual documents. There is a limit of 16MB per document. That means when you embed the messages in the user document you will only have space for a few thousand messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to keep the messages as individual documents.

The reason is that MongoDB doesn't work well with documents which grow over time.

For performance reasons, MongoDB keeps each document in a contiguous region in the database files. That means when a document grows beyond its original size, MongoDB has to reallocate new disk space for it and move it there. Having to do this all the time really reduce write performance.

I also think that you rarely need *all* the messages of a given user. Usually you only want the unread ones or you want to paginate them. Both doesn't work well with embedded arrays.

Comment: System Sends Automatic Text Message and Email Alerts to user.

Comment: @SangNguyen When it's fully automatized you will sooner or later have some bug or unusual event which generates thousands of messages in a short time period or creates unusually large messages. That will crack the 16MB per document limit when you embed.

Answer (score -1):

I would highly recommend embed, its going to mean less calls to mongo, its cleaner and its the recommended way is to create single documents that relate to your view.

Mongo db as default allows 16 meg per document. So for two people messaging this would mean roughly 30 million short messages embedded.

I have just implemented  a messaging schema, using the following schema. This supports a top level messages overview screen per user and then the message thread for each message. All works very nicely.

{

```
"FromUserId" : Number,
"ToUserId" : Number,
"FromStatus" : Number,
"ToStatus" : Number,
"Preview" : String,
"Sent" : Date,
"Read" : Date,
"ToUsername" : String,
"FromUsername" : String,
"Messages" :[{
    "FromUserId" : Number,
    "ToUserId" : Number,
    "FromStatus" : Number,
    "ToStatus" : Number,
    "MessageContent" : String,
    "IP" : String,
    "Sent" : Date,
    "Read" : Date,
    "RelId" : Date
    }]
```

}

Comment: This could have been done just as easily with non-embedded, and in fact may be more efficient depending on the nature of queries required and data retrieval requirements. The problem is that the question provided no real details and is too broad.

Comment: Your space calculation of 30 million messages is far off. 16 MB are roughly 16 million bytes. When each short message is about 256 bytes (text + meta-data), that would be about 60.000 short messages. Still much, but possible to reach for chatty people over the course of several years. Also, short messages could become much larger than that when you would add different features later, like file attachments.