# Mongodb with relationships

Tags: mongodb

I am new to document stores (mongodb specifically), but would like to know when one will use embedded relationships and when will one use references? as defined in http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/

My guess is if the relationship is used only in one place it should be embedded else use a reference?

What is the implications of this decision?

Comment: Have you tried searching around, there are many questions on the topic, including: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373198/mongodb-relationships-embed-or-reference

Answer (score 0):

Well, the link you went through does state pretty clearly:

> In general, use normalized data models:
>
> 1. when embedding would result in duplication of data but would not
>    provide sufficient read performance advantages to outweigh the
>    implications of the duplication.
> 2. to represent more complex many-to-many relationships.
> 3. to model large hierarchical data sets.

I think though that for the majority of cases, MongoDB is optimized to handle queries on embedded data. It was built to do this well, and the whole point of MongoDB (I believe) is to eliminate joins and normalization. You **should** be trying to put as much data inside the documents themselves as possible.

The page also states certain disadvantages of using references when the same can be achieved with embedding (you may find that this is often the case):

> However, client-side applications must issue follow-up queries to resolve the references. In other words, normalized data models can require more round trips to the server.

Additionally, if you use too many references rather than embedding data, you may lose the guaranteed consistency advantage that a document provides since operations on documents are atomic but otherwise are not.