# alter field by number in nested array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Let's say there is a data structure containing objects like

```
{ 
  name : 'ernie',
  likes : [
  {
    what : 'rubber duckie',
    howmuch : 5
  },
  {
    what : 'bert',
    howmuch : 3
  }]
}
```

and

```
{ 
  name : 'cookie monster',
  likes : [
  {
    what : 'cookies',
    howmuch : 100
  }]
}
```

If the `0`th element of `ernie`'s `likes`-array should have its `howmuch`-value incremented, say, by 1, is there a MongoDB command to do this? The JavaScript-equivalent would be `ernie.likes[0].howmuch++`.

Specifically, **can you access the elements of an array by index number**?

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain the downvote, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increment the `howmuch` field value by 1 of the `0`th element of ernie's likes-array, use the **[`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/)** operator together with the **[dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)** to access the element of the array by the zero-based index position:

```
db.collection.update(
    {
        "name": "ernie"       
    }, 
    { 
        "$inc" : { "likes.0.howmuch" : 1 } 
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

do you want to create index on array? if yes, you have to create index on 'likes' array. with this code : `db.sample.createIndex ({likes : 1})` . or more specifically, you have to create `db.sample.createIndex ({'likes.howmuch': 1})`

After index creation, you can access array elements with index.

Comment: I did not want to create an index. (the wording is unfortunate, though). The question asks for a **mongo equivalent of `ernie.likes[0].howmuch++`**. (If you want to edit the question to make this more clear, feel free)

Comment: first version, I understood that you need an index, sorry. @chridam's answer is right.