# from relation table to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to create a MongoDB design (but I'm new at mongo) based on a relation database schema.

My question is: **How far do I denormalize my schema?**:

```
-Users
--Wallets[field1,field2]
---Items[field1,field2]
----Transactions[field1,field2]
--....
```

`Users` -> linked to a lot of tables.
`Wallets` -> a user can have more wallets.
`Items` -> a wallet can have more Items(the field values of Items will not regulary change).
`Transactions` -> a item can have more Transactions.
My idea is to:

1. Split Users in a document
2. Group Wallets and Transactions (create a reference to `User_id` (at the wallet level) and `Item_id` (on the transaction level)) in a document
3. Items in a document

Will this be a right approach?

As to why MongoDB: it is because I'm creating a Meteor App.

Comment: Do wallets and transactions need to have the possibility of being linked to multiple users? Or does each wallet and transaction have one user?

Comment: wallet and transaction have one user

Comment: The MongoDB Docs contains a good section on [Data Models](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/) in MongoDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to @inspired's answer (which translates your schema straight to MongoDB and models [via document references](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)), it might be easier to [embed data into the user document](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/).

If you choose to embed, it would look like:

```
{ name: 'username',
  id: ObjectId("512512a5d86041c7dca81914"),
  wallets: [ {
    wallet_name: 'its_name_if_required',
    field_one: 'its_content',
    field_two: 'its_content',
    items: [ {
      item_field_one: 'content_item_1',
      item_field_one: 'other_content_item_1',
      transactions: [ {
        whatever: 1,
        a_transaction: 'some string',
        contains: new Date()
      }, {
        whatever: 1,
        another_transaction: 'some string',
        contains: new Date()
      } ] // end transactions
    }, {
       // another item, omitted for brevity
    } ] // end items
  }, {
    // another wallet, omitted for brevity again
  } ] // end wallets
} // end user
```

This allows easy accessing of f.ex. transactions via

```
user.wallets[0].items[1].transactions[0].whatever
```

Note that not all transactions *have to* have the same fields. Here, `transactions[1]` has a field named `another_transaction`. Note also that JSON does not allow comments (they are for understanding better).

A limitation of this is the 16MB document maximum size of MongoDB.

If each user amasses more than 16 MB of total data, you will probably implement @inspired's answer or something in between, where you store (for example) everything up to items inside the user, together with a list of `transaction_id`s. But *it depends on how many transactions you expect and how often they are going to change*.

For the question of embedding vs referencing, see [MongoDB relationships: embed or reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373198/mongodb-relationships-embed-or-reference).

Comment: If Items change a lot and Transactions don't really change but are added a lot. Would you go with the embedded solution?

Comment: @Phoenix: I might go all-embedded, but would probably separate items out into a separate document. If a user's item's transactions can grow to more than 16 MB, you *have to* reference. If not, embeddings are much easier to work with (as also said in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373198/mongodb-relationships-embed-or-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Since MongoDB has no joining facilities you will be either embedding data or referencing to it. There are trade-offs for both, and when trying to decide which to do you can look at this criteria.

**Embedding is better for...**

- Small subdocuments
- Data that does not change regularly
- When eventual consistency is acceptable
- Documents that grow by a small amount
- Data that you’ll often need to perform a second query to fetch
- Fast reads

**References are better for...**

- Large subdocuments
- Volatile data
- When immediate consistency is necessary
- Documents that grow a large amount
- Data that you’ll often exclude from the results
- Fast writes

**For your scenario it looks like you would have the following**

**User Document** - Referencing Wallets

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("512512a5d86041c7dca81914"),
   "name" : "John Doe",
   "wallets" : [
     ObjectId("512512ced86041c7dca81916"),
     ObjectId("512512ced86041c7dca81917"),
     ObjectId("512512ced86041c7dca81918"),
    ]
}
```

**Wallets Documents** - Reference Items

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("512512a5d86041c7dca81913"),
    "items": [
         ObjectId("512512ced86041c7dca81916"),
         ObjectId("512512ced86041c7dca81920"),
         ObjectId("512512ced86041c7dca81921"),
    ]
}
```

**Items** - Referencing Transactions

```
    {
         "_id" : ObjectId("512512a5d86041c7dca81913"),
         "transactions" : [
             ObjectId("512512ced86041c7dca81952"),
             ObjectId("512512ced86041c7dca81953"),
             ObjectId("512512ced86041c7dca81954")
          ],
          other fields..
     },
```

**Transaction Document**

```
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("512512a5d86041c7dca81914"),
     other fields...
}
```

Comment: Is this way difficult to retreive the all the data from the database: For example User x all tranactions?

Comment: @Phoenix will wallets, items, or transactions need to be accessed outside of the user collection?