# Best way to structure my mongoose schema: embedded array , populate, subdocument?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

### Here is my current Schema

Brand:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var BrandSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, lowercase: true , unique: true, required: true },
  photo: { type: String , trim: true},
  email: { type: String , lowercase: true},
  year: { type: Number},
  timestamp: { type : Date, default: Date.now },
  description: { type: String},
  location: { },
  social: {
    website: {type: String},
    facebook: {type: String },
    twitter: {type: String },
    instagram: {type: String }
  }
});
```

Style:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var StyleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, lowercase: true , required: true},
});
```

Product

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, lowercase: true , required: true},
  brandId : {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Brand'},
  styleId: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Style'},
  year: { type: Number }, 
  avgRating: {type: Number}
});
```

Post:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  rating: { type: Number},
  upVote: {type: Number},
  brandId : {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Brand'},
  comment: {type: String},
  productId: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Style'},
  styleId: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Style'},
  photo: {type: String}
});
```

---

I'm currently making use of the mongoose populate feature:

```
exports.productsByBrand = function(req, res){
  Product.find({product: req.params.id}).populate('style').exec(function(err, products){
    res.send({products:products});
  });
};
```

---

This works, however, being a noob --- i've started reading about performance issues with the mongoose populate, since it's really just adding an additional query.

For my post , especially, it seems that could be taxing. The intent for the post is to be a live twitter / instagram-like feed. It seems that could be a lot of queries, which could greatly slow my app down.

also, I want to be able to search prodcuts / post / brand by fields at some point.

Should i consider nesting / embedding this data (products nested / embedded in brands)?

What's the most efficient schema design or would my setup be alright -- given what i've specified I want to use it for?

---

***User story:***

***There will be an Admin User.***

The admin will be able to add the *Brand* with the specific fields in the *Brand* Schema.

Brands will have associated *Products*, each *Product* will have a *Style* / category.

---

***Search:***

Users will be able to search *Brands* by name and location (i'm looking into doing this with angular filtering / tags).

Users will be able to search *Products* by fields (name, style, etc).

Users will be able to search *Post* by *Brand* *Product* and *Style*.

---

***Post:***

Users will be able to *Post* into a *feed.* When making a *Post*, they will choose a *Brand* and a *Product* to associate the *Post* with. The *Post* will display the *Brand* name, *Product* name, and *Style* -- along with newly entered *Post* fields (photo, comment, and rating).

Other users can click on the *Brand* name to link to the *Brand* show page. They can click on the *Product* name to link to a *Product* show page.

**Product show page:**

Will show *Product* fields from the above Schema -- including associated *Style* name from *Style* schema. It will also display *Post* pertaining to the specific *Product*.

***Brand show page:***

Will simply show *Brand* fields and associated products.

---

My main worry is the *Post*, which will have to populate / query for the *Brand* , *Product*, and *Style* within a feed.

Again, I'm contemplating if I should embed the *Products* within the *Brand* -- then would I be able to associate the *Brand* *Product* and *Style* with the *Post* for later queries? Or, possibly $lookup or other aggregate features.

Comment: This should probably be closed as a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373198/mongodb-relationships-embed-or-reference

Comment: @JohnnyHK I am not too sure, since we are talking of the additional intricacies Mongoose introduces.

Comment: The data models themselves tell only half the story (if it is that much). Way more important are the user stories and / or use cases. Data modeling in MongoDB _starts_ with them, then you derive the question your data needs to answer, and _only_ then you model your data. So in order to answer your question, the user stories / use cases should be included.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @MarkusWMahlberg. I've added a brief user story.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mongodb itself does not support joins. So, mongoose populate is an attempt at external reference resolution. The thing with mongodb is that you need to design your data so that:

1. most of you queries need not to refer multiple collections.
2. after getting data from query, you need not to transform it too much.

Consider the entities involved, and their relations:

1. Brand is brand. Doesn't depend on anything else.
2. Every Product belongs to a Brand.
3. Every Product is associated with a Style.
4. Every Post is associated with a Product.
5. Indirectly, every Post is associated to a Brand and Style, via product.

Now about the use cases:

1. **Refer:** If you are looking up one entity by id, then fetching 1-2 related entities is not really a big overhead.
2. **List:** It is when you have to return a large set of objects and each object needs an additional query to get associated objects. This is a performance  issue. This is usually reduced by processing "pages" of result set at a time, say 20 records per request. Lets suppose you query 20 products (using `skip` and `limit`). For 20 products you extract two id arrays, one of referred styles, and other of referred brands. You do 2 additional queries using `$in:[ids]`, get brands and styles object and place them in result set. That's 3 queries per page. Users can request next page as they scroll down, and so on.
3. **Search:** You want to search for products, but also want to specify brand name and style name. Sadly, product model only holds ids for style and brand. Same issue with searching Posts with brand and product. Popular solution is to maintain a separate "search index", a sort of table, that stores data exactly the way it will be searched for, with all searchable fields (like brand name, style name) at one place. Maintaining such search collections in mongodb manually can be a pain. This is where [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) comes in. Since you are already using mongoose, you can simply add [mongoosastic](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic) to your models. ElasticSearch's search capabilities are far greater than a DB Storage engine will offer you.
4. **Extra Speed:** There is still some room for speeding things up: Caching. Attach [mongoose-redis-cache](https://github.com/conancat/mongoose-redis-cache) and have frequent repeated queries served, in-memory from [Redis](http://redis.io/), reducing load on mongodb.
5. **Twitter like Feeds:** Now if all Posts are public then listing them up for users in chronological order is a trivial query. However things change when you introduce "social networking" features. Then you need to list "activity feeds" of friends and followers. There's some wisdom about social inboxes and Fan-out lists [in mongodb blog](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65612078649/schema-design-for-social-inboxes-in-mongodb).

Moral of the story is that not all use cases have only "db schema query" solutions. Scalability is one of such cases. That's why other tools exist.

Comment: I do have an infinite-scroll paging setup for the post (as you suggest). Do you think having this with the separated schemas would be adequate? The more I read up on mongodb schemas, i'm almost feeling I should maybe embed Styles into Brands, then embed related Products under Styles -- to take advantage of NoSQL pre joins.

Comment: @NoobSter Yes you can embed documents, but then you have to handle updating all copies of an object in multiple collections, every time it changes. This will become harder and harder to track as complexity will grow. Another thing is that a document can hold only up to 16 mb of data. So, you wouldn't be able to embed a large number of objects.