# confusion in designing db document using mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I use to design 'table' like this

```
teacher
- id
- name

student
- id
- teacher_id
- name
```

Just assume 1 teacher can have many students, so I put teacher_id to be able to do join.

But in noSql why should I do multiple document? I can put everything under `user` and use nested object like

```
   user = {[
    id:1,
    type:teacher
    student:[{
    id:321
    }]
]}
```

Imagine my app need to retrieve a list of teacher and student in different tab, still with model I can get the data I need, I just do the filter/manipulation on the client side, correct?

Comment: This is similar to previous questions like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373198/mongodb-relationships-embed-or-reference

Answer (score 2):

if you use `nodejs` then i preferred you is to use `moongose` npm on your node.It use schema and model restriction.Your approach is fine in `RDBMS` but in mongo you avoid to make joins.

Desgin a schema in this way that match according to your requirements and usage of data availabilty and `read or write` operations

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

```
var Teachers = new Schema({
        //_id: ObjectId,
        "name": {
            "type": String,
        },
         "students": [{
            name: String
            }]
        })

module.exports = mongoose.model('Teachers', Teachers);
```

It avoids your join.it manage all the teachers with their respective students.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter on the server side and send the filtered data to client. It's more efficient.

Comment: but is my approach on how to design schema acceptable? because of the nature of nosql is flexible I don't have to be too 'careful' in defining my db schema? right?