# design noSQL database mongoose nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-design, mongoose

I build booking appointments barbershop app in react native with node js mongoose.
in short, each user can make an appointment to barber. each barber has some types of hair cuts types.

user - Appointment (many to many) -> should I need to add appointment array in user?

Appointment - users (many to many) -> ref: **user_id**.

Barber- Appointment (many to many)-> **should I need to add appointment array in user?**

Appointment - Barber(many to many) ref: **barber_id**

Barber- HairCut Types(many to many): ref: **types** array

that's my demo design
[image]

I would like to know if the db design looks right? do I need to save appointments array in user and barber also?

Comment: My opinion. In doubt. I'd use a RDBMS.

Comment: why? this db not complex

Comment: maybe you are right, If it's your business the time will says.

Comment: why do you think it's better way RDBMS?

Comment: I don't know if rdbms i better, I know that rdbms is flexible.

Comment: The 2 questions you asked depend on the needs of your business, depends on how you'll develop your system. I think it's good to have in both, but you need to choose between embedded or reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373198/mongodb-relationships-embed-or-reference

Comment: I said it depends because adding relationship increases complexity and  size of your database, but I think both are very cheap in this case.