# How to index a non unique key in mongodb?

Tags: arrays, node.js, database, mongodb

I am creating a project related to the blogs.
Let say I have a blog post and in that, I want to maintain comments and likes against a post.

How can I achieve it? I have created a collection of blog post and in the same, I have an array of comments. But if I think of long term, this might not be the best approach.

Can someone please suggest me the best way to maintain such activity?

And is it possible to index a non unique key in a schema?

Like if I want to create another collection for comments and likes, how to retrieve the comments against a blog? I can but without index it would be slow when data is too much.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373198/mongodb-relationships-embed-or-reference. And yes, indexes don't have to be unique.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of making index on a non unique key? 

db.items.createIndex( { “item" : 1 } ) ? shall it work if item has similar values in a collection?

Comment: Seems like a pretty easy thing to test especially since you already have the command to create the index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good afternoon, I can provide an answer to one of your questions: is it possible to index a non unique key in a schema?

Yes. In mongosh you can use the following code:

```
db.collection.createIndex({field: 1 (or -1)})
```

This specifies a non-unique index field.

As an added bonus, if you want to use a unique field then you can use the following code:

```
db.collection.createIndex({field: 1 (or -1)}, {unique: true})
```

Cheers