# Reference within MongoDB/Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373198/mongodb-relationships-embed-or-reference) where it is discussed if references between documents should be established. I want to annotate my `Java` class so that references within `JSON` documents are created:

```
{
    "id": "3",
    "bs": [
        {
            "name": "abc"
        },
        {
            "name": "def",
            "preconditions": ["abc"]
        },
        {
            "name": "ghi",
            "preconditions":  ["abc"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here the objects of the list preconditions have references to objects of the list bs. Is that possible in `MongoDB`? How is it called (I was unable to find any information using the keywords "embedded reference" and "reference within documents".) How would a solution look like with [morphia](https://morphia.dev/)?

EDIT:I know the [reference](https://morphia.dev/1.4/guides/annotations/#reference) annotation but it seems to refernce to anoter collection and not to a list of objects in the same document. I just want to ensure, that the serialized java objects are deserialized correctly (both attributes should become references to the same object).

EDIT II: To clarify my problem I provide the code which I used for testing:

Class A

```
@Entity("MyAs")
public class A {
    @Id
    public String name;

    @Embedded
    public List<B> bs=new LinkedList<B>();
}
```

Class B

```
public class B {
    @Id
    public String bName;

    public List<B> preconditions=new LinkedList<B>(); 
}
```

In my main method I do the following:

```
final Datastore datastore = morphia.createDatastore(new MongoClient(), 
"Test");
B b1=new B();
b1.bName="b1";

B b2=new B();
b2.bName="b2";

b1.preconditions.add(b2);

List<B> bs=new LinkedList<B>();
bs.add(b1);
bs.add(b2);

A a1=new A();
a1.name="mya1";
a1.bs=bs;

datastore.save(a1);

A myA=datastore.get(A.class,"mya1");
System.out.println(myA.bs.get(0).preconditions.get(0));
System.out.println(myA.bs.get(0).preconditions.get(0).hashCode()+" --"  +myA.bs.get(0).preconditions.get(0).bName);
System.out.println(myA.bs.get(1));
System.out.println(myA.bs.get(1).hashCode() +" --" +  myA.bs.get(1).bName);
```

This leads to the following structure in Mongo DB Compass (obviously, no reference is created):
[image]

If the document is deserialized then (with datastore.get), obviously two separate objects are created for b2 (outputs of `System.out.println`):

```
mongotest.B@78b729e6
2025269734 --b2
mongotest.B@6b4a4e18
1800031768 --b2
```

I want to have a structure where the b2 object in preconditions references to the b2 object in bs!

If I do `datastore.get(A.class,"mya1");` I want to have the same structure which I used for  the serialization: a single B object which is referenced in the bs list and in the preconditions..

Comment: How are you serlializing it?  There are going to be 2 B objects because that's how you've modeled it. in the database, they'll still be nested documents inside your A document.  With the above code, how does it look in the database?  Morphia doesn't require @Id annotations for embedded documents but you have them and that might be leading to some confusion for you.

Comment: Thank you for your effort; I updated my post: I want to annotate my Java code so that the reference in the JSON object is created. When I deserialize the JSON to Java I want to have a single B object which is referenced in the preconditions list as well as in the bs list (currently I get two B objects after deserialization, but I only refered to a single B object when I do the serialization to JSON)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create *that* structure, you'd simply have a `List<B>` on your entity and annotate that field with `@Embedded`.  See [here](https://morphia.dev/1.4/guides/annotations/#embedded) for a bit more documentation.

Comment: thank you for your effort - I think you missinterpreted my question -> I tried to use embedded which doesnt lead to the desired result

Comment: so you want those nested Bs to be references to another collection?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my MonogDB collection and retried to run my example: Now it seems to work. The b in preconditions referes to the the object in the bs array. The embedded annotation is required!