# MongoDB inserting multiple subdocuments

Tags: mongodb

Need to use insert() to add multiple subdocuments inside an empty collection.
Syntax is wrong,please help.

```
db.boeken.insert({
    "_id":"A001",
    "auteur":"Stieg Larsson",
    "boek":["titel":"Mannen die vrouwen haten","jaartal":2005],["titel":"De vrouw die met vuur speelde","jaartal":2006]   
})
```

Returns :

```
[js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing ] after element list :
@(shell):1:71
```

Comment: look like malformed `json`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB relationships: embed or reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373198/mongodb-relationships-embed-or-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the array `boek` is malformed.

You can have 3 kinds of arrays inside a Mongo document:

**1- Array of Values:**

```
{
    "_id": "some_id",
    "some_numbers": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "some_words": ["salt", "bird", "beer"]
}
```

**2- Array of Arrays:**

```
{
    "_id": "some_id",
    "some_arrays": [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        ["salt", "bird", "beer"]
    ]
}
```

**3- Array of documents (that's your case):**

```
{
    "_id": "some_id",
    "boek":[
        {
            "titel":"Mannen die vrouwen haten",
            "jaartal":2005
        },
        {
            "titel":"De vrouw die met vuur speelde",
            "jaartal":2006
        }
   ]   
}
```

That said, if you want to use `key:value` for the elements of the array `boek`, that means that you have an **array of documents**. The problem with your code is that you are missing the `{}` for each element of the array.

So, in your case, the correct code would be:

```
db.boeken.insert({
    "_id":"A001",
    "auteur":"Stieg Larsson",
    "boek":[
        {
            "titel":"Mannen die vrouwen haten",
            "jaartal":2005
        },
        {
            "titel":"De vrouw die met vuur speelde",
            "jaartal":2006
        }
    ]   
})
```

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted, please. It can help other devs with the same problem.