# MongoDB best practise - One to many relation

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

According to this post I should **embed** a "reference": [MongoDB relationships: embed or reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373198/mongodb-relationships-embed-or-reference)

### User.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdEvents: ['Event']
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

### Event.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const eventSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);
```

So an embedded event looks like this in the database:

[image]

My Code works but im curious if this is the right way to embed the event. Because every example for *one to many* relations is made with references and not embedded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, using **embedding** or **referencing** depends on how much data we are dealing with.

When deciding on which approach to pick, You should always consider:

1- **One-To-Few:** if you'll have a small number of **events** added to a **user** over time, I recommend you to pick the [**embedding**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/) approach as it is simpler to deal with.

2- **One-To-Many:** if new **events** are frequently added, you totally should go for [**referencing**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/) to avoid future performance issues.

Why?

When you are frequently adding new **events**, if they are being embedded inside an **user** document, that document will grow larger and larger over time. In the future you will probably face issues like I/O overhead. You can catch a glimpse of the evils of large arrays in the article [Why shouldn't I embed large arrays in my documents?](http://www.askasya.com/post/largeembeddedarrays/). Although it's hard to find it written anywhere, large arrays in MongoDB are considered a performance anti-pattern.

If you decide to go for **referencing**, I suggest reading [Building with Patterns: The Bucket Pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-bucket-pattern). The article can give you an idea on how to design your **user_events** collection in a non-relational way.