# MongoDB - Posting and getting user specific data

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I'm building a MEAN stack application with passport auth and just wanted to know the best approach to storing and getting user specific data.

So say for a simple example I had a collection of users and a collection of fruits stored inside a database.

The user can add a favourite fruit, which will be stored in the fruits collection against their specific user ID. When they return to the app at a later stage, I can get all the favourite fruits for that specific user and display them on the page.

Would the best approach be to store these fruits in a separate collection?

Or should they be stored in that specific user document in the users collection?

In terms of then getting the data back, would I have to check the user ID of the logged in user and then get all of the favourites for that user ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking about reference or embedded. This link [MongoDB relationships: embed or reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373198/mongodb-relationships-embed-or-reference) may answer your questions.