# How to establish a foreign key relationship in MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, postgresql

I have a postgreSQL database that has 3 tables named `customer`, `product` and `purchase_order`. Every table has `id_` as the primary key. Table `purchase_order` also has `customer_id` (`id_` field of `customer` table) and `product_id` (`id_` field of `product` table) as foreign keys.

I want to create the same DB on MongoDB. However, I'm not sure how to establish foreign keys. I have researched it and found out that it is pretty much up to me how to do it. So, this is how I did `purchase_order` table on MongoDB:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5f5639cdb675b2a13db059b3"},
"customer_id":{"$oid":"5f563a08b675b2a13db059b1"},
"product_id":{"$oid":"5f563a13b675b2a13db059b2"},
"status":false}
```

My goal is to write a spring application to perform CRUD methods. On postgreSQL, I added foreign key constraints on DB and `@OneToMany` & `@ManyToOne` annotations on my code to establish foreign keys. However, I'm not sure how to do it for MongoDB. Does my MongoDB document correctly represent the foreign keys? How can I make sure to establish my foreign keys on my spring application for MongoDB?

Comment: MongoDB has no concept of foreign key constraint, like in a relational database. Here is general documentation on [Data Models](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/data-modeling/index.html) for MongoDB. Data can have entities with relationships (1:N, N:N, etc.), but these are modeled for MongoDB documents and flexible schema. Also see: [SQL to MongoDB Chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/sql-comparison/index.html).

Answer (score 5):

If you are using JavaScript on your backend, what you are looking for can be easily achieved with Mongoose!

This involves creating a Schema for an entity and specifying a `ref` property for the entity's foreign key field/column that matches the name of an existing model.

Following this, whenever you query the database for a single document, you can also add or populate the details for the foreign key field.

Kindly view this on [getting started with mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html) if you are not using it or familiar with it, and then move on to this documentation which provides examples for [populating the foreign key field](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) when you make a query.

In your specific case a given schema could look like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CustomerSchema = new Schema({
   _id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  }
  // Other relevant fields
})

const ProductSchema = new Schema({
   _id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  }
  // Other relevant fields
})

const ProductOrderSchema = new Schema({
  _id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  },
  customer_id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Customer'
  },
  product_id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Product'
  }
});

// Your models
const Customer = mongoose.model('Customer', CustomerSchema);
const Product = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
const ProductOrder = mongoose.model('ProductOrder', ProductOrderSchema);
```

Hope you can get this sorted out relatively easily!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry if miss the point but I use JSON format for my streams. Would it still be possible to use mongoose as you suggested?

Comment: What language are you using? JavaScript? If yes, mongoose should fit in easy.

Comment: @rexessilfie when to use nested docs and when to use foregin key?

Comment: That is a great question with many nuances to consider! This post discusses embedding (for example with sub-documents) vs a separate document (with a ref): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373198/mongodb-relationships-embed-or-reference