# How can I make MongoDB find by key more efficient

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, find

I have a one to many relationship between "region" and "story" collections. I.e. each region has multiple stories. The story collection contains every story for every region with a "regionId" key that identifies what region that story belongs to. I am going to need to lookup stories associated with various regionIds, presumably using `Story.find{"regionId" : <regionId>}` In the future there could be thousands or millions of total stories and am aware doing a collection search would be very inefficient. Initially I made a "stories" field in "regions" so I could lookup by _id but I realized that would create a reference nightmare. My question is, can I just index the "regionId" field to accomplish what I want, even though there are multiple documents with the same regionId?

```
storySchema.createIndex{ { regionId: 1  } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout mongoDB aggregations.
You would do something like:

```js
Story.aggregation([
 {
  $match: {
    region: regionId
    }
 }
])
```

Comment: Do you think I should just scrap the Story collection and store them in subdocuments  of Region? I would've thought that that would create memory problems since the docs would be huge but I guess that's good practice according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373198/mongodb-relationships-embed-or-reference

Comment: I think it is a better practice to keep the data in separate collections, and reference it instead. You can check this: https://web.archive.org/web/20110111033238/http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design#SchemaDesign-Embedvs.Reference  to get a better understanding for your use case